# VS Code updates on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: visual-studio-code

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I can no longer update my VS Code application.  I tried both the DEB and SNAP packages.  My current Visual Studio Code version is 1.52.1, but I can't update to the latest. I get a message from the installer: "Failed to Install file: not supported."

Answer (score 0):

After an upgrade the PPA sources used by `apt` are commented out. They can be found in `/etc/apt/. These are mine:

```sh
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list*
/etc/apt/sources.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade  /etc/apt/sources.list.save

/etc/apt/sources.list.d:
atom.list  keybase.list  nodesource.list  sbt.list  vscode.list  yarn.list
```

You can discover the sources that were commented like this:

```sh
$ grep -r vscode /etc/apt/sources.list*
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main # disabled on upgrade to groovy
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main
```

Do not uncomment entries that start with `deb-src`, just the ones that start with `deb`.

After uncommenting, remember to run:

```sh
$ sudo apt update
$ yes | sudo apt upgrade
```

However, VSCode can update itself. Use the VSCode **Help / Check for Updates** menu.